# Can I edit WMS layer or KML layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, vector

I am using OpenLayers and until now I have been using OSM as background and I got points from my database (mySQL) and added them to vector layer, then I could modify them and save it back to the server.

Now I am not using OSM any more, I got data as a shapefile, and this is the background of the map, I am using GeoServer to show the files.

I want to make an option to modify these layers (WMS). I can't insert everything to the database because it's too much and the map will work slowly if I will add the data from the database.

So I need a way to modify the vectors that I am getting from GeoServer and to save the changes, or if its not possible, maybe to do it with KML layer (but this is a bad option).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you need WFS-T Service to be editing your data in web browser http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34131/wfs-t-edit-using-openlayers-geoserver-postgresql-error-performing-insert

Comment: `So I need a way to modify the vectors that I am getting from GeoServer` you aren't getting any vectors from GeoServer, you're getting an image of your vectors