# How I can insert feature attribute after feature drawing complete

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, database, fields-attributes

I am new to OpenLayers. I am trying to insert wfs feature information to my map after drawing like [this](http://dev4.mapgears.com/bdga/bdgaWFS-T.html).
I can draw a WFS  feature like (polygon, line, point) on map and after drawing the feature  complete I can insert attribute information of feature (like polygon name, area, etc) into permanently. That is after refresh the map the feature (polygon) visible on the map and on click on the feature (polygon) the feature attribute information is display by popup.
I have done drawing feature on the map by finding the some demo on Google.
But I do not understand how to store the feature attribute. Currently  I am using Geoserver  and  shapefile on  Geoserver  for layer  and  fetching  this shapefile as layer in open layer by  WFS  service of Geoserver.

Now my question is:

How to store feature attribute by using Shapefile or Database (PostgresSQL)?
If we use shapefile as WFS layer then, it is possible to store feature attribute after drawing the feature in shapefile by fetching it from Geoserver in OpenLayers.

or

For storing the feature attribute we should use Database (PostgresSQL)?
I am totally new to OpenLayers. I don’t know which way is better. I want that I am able to draw feature on  OpenLayers map  and I can insert attribute information of feature by popup and save this feature  on the map.

My website Url is: http://mindcrewgis.com/

Comment: Have a look 

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40648/how-do-i-set-attributes-when-creating-vectors-using-openlayers-and-wfs-t

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, this is the advance OpenLayer tutorial

http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

Comment: Also do check this example   http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2009-August/013239.html

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52818/how-to-connect-openlayers-to-postgis-data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106262/getting-the-user-click-inputs-in-openlayers-and-store-in-postgis

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34131/wfs-t-edit-using-openlayers-geoserver-postgresql-error-performing-insert