# Saving to database on OpenLayers map changes?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-service, oracle-spatial

I have put a map on website using OpenLayers. This map is fetched from geoserver by using wms request. and in the same way, it is drawn some shapes such as point, line etc. using open layers library in this simple project.

My Spatial data(tables) is held on Oracle spatial database. as I mentioned above, these tables are served by geoserver to the web page and are mapped using open layers library.

How can I save new changes on map to related to Database Table When I draw a new shape on this map?

[image: unchanged image(which is fetched via geoserver)]

[image: changed image(some shapes is drawn on map that is called changed image)]

When it has occurred changes, the second image was created.

Comment: look into WFS-T technology

Comment: please more help as code because ı am fresh on web development

Comment: here is a good tutorial: http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

Comment: also this question I believe has a working code: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34131/wfs-t-edit-using-openlayers-geoserver-postgresql-error-performing-insert

Comment: these links weren't helpful for me.

Comment: here is a working exampe --> https://jsfiddle.net/h7mk0jpt/ and here is the tutorial explaining the code of the provided example -->https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58